# IdentityServer 4 and sso

Tags: asp.net-core, single-sign-on, identityserver4

I try to implement sso using IdentityServer4. I use standard examples from its docs.
I have three applications.

Application A -- identityserver implementation that configured using asp.net identity and entity framework.

Application B, C -- web-applications as clients.

Flow:

I go to an secured action of application A and next I redirect to sign in form of identityserver, enter my credential and i redirect back to my client -- it's ok. When next i open any secured action of application B i again redirect to sign in form of idenityserver.

So my question

Is it correct behavior? I just think that sso developed as signing in one place and then automatically login from other related. So if i am wrong please correct me but if not please give me any help what could I missed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> It is the correct behavior.The token is given for an application
>   specific and will only work for that application only.

When you [define your client](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/clients.html),your each client will have it's own **client id** and **secret** and **allowed scopes**. So for any client ,it will be different client ID  and secret. And then there is different flow based on [grant types](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/grant_types.html)